# How do I send html code as parameter in Flask?

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask, parameters

I have the following piece of code:

```
def factura():
    tabla = calcularfactura.calcularfactura("27-03", "24-04")
    codigo = pd.DataFrame.to_html(tabla)
    return render_template("factura.html", codigo = codigo)
```

Which turns a Pandas Dataframe into a bunch of HTML code.

Now, I would like to paint that HTML into the body of an existing HTML template. More or less something like:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

  {{codigo}}

{% endblock %}
```

But all I get is the actual text of the HTML code, instead of the expected table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
...
{{codigo|safe}}
...
```

You find more information [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping).